# moving away from character

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to have some enemies run away from my player.  I found code to move toward the play and made it the opposite.  The problem is they speed up really fast when running away.  If i make the code back to running towards the character they move at a normal pace.  Why is this?

Running away

```
Vector2 velocity = new Vector2((transform.position.x - player.position.x) * speed, (transform.position.y - player.position.y) * speed);
rigidbody2D.velocity = velocity;
```

running towards

```
Vector2 velocity = new Vector2((transform.position.x - player.position.x) * speed, (transform.position.y - player.position.y) * speed);
rigidbody2D.velocity = -velocity;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the characters would actually slow down as they approach you... that's what the code you wrote would do.

Basically, you have `(End - Start) * Speed`... which means that the length of `End - Start` is multiplied by speed. So if the character is 5m away, velocity = 5m * speed, etc.

What you need is `((End - Start) / (End - Start).Length()) * Speed`.

By dividing by the length of `End - Start`, you remove the distance from the equation, and get purely a direction multiplied by the wanted speed.

Comment: Thats correct.  Thanks.  I grabbed this code without fully understanding it.  I changed it to
    Vector2 direction = transform.position - player.transform.position;
   direction.Normalize();
   transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, direction * minDistance, Time.deltaTime * speed);